# Run TensorFlow remotely

Tags: python, linux, ssh, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow, Linux, and ML. I am trying to use a GPU in another system in my lab for training my model. I have connected to the system using SSH.

Now what I am stuck on is how should I write the python code? One thing I can do is run python in the terminal window where I can see the username of the other machine I am connected to but it takes a lot of efforts and is not an efficient way of doing it.

What I want to do is write the python code in a file(on my machine) and run it on the machine possessing GPU. Can you describe to me how I should do that?

P.S: I understand it is a very basic doubt but I would appreciate if you can help me with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to plug my own site, but I [described how to do this with Pycharm in a blogpost.](http://www.pinchofintelligence.com/faster-writing-and-testing-machine-learning-applications/)

Really hope this helps you out! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: I would keep it a second resort but if I can get a specific(without using external programs/libraries/modules) solution to my problem it would be better.

Comment: Using a remote interpreter is really neat! Judging by your question are you saying that neither @rmeertens solution or SSH is acceptable?

Comment: If neither is acceptable I would recommend you to take a look at Docker, perhaps building a docker machine that downloads your code could work? But honestly I think that Pycharm is the best thing ever (it even prompted me to spend time to write a blogpost).

Answer (score 5):

Tensorflow has a [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) tutorial out now.  Since you can connect over SSH, this is an option.